# Laravel How to fulfill edit function if form is datetimepicker or dropdown list?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to fulfil edit function if the form is a dropdown list or DateTime picker?

Here are some of my code. The code basically is from my create function, but I know it will be different, it will be an array

```
<h2>Edit Tasks</h2>
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'TasksController@store','method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

```
     {{Form::label('filetype','FileType')}}
     {{Form::select('filetype', array('pdf' => 'PDF', 'word' => 'Word','url' =>'URL',), 'pdf',['class'=>'form-control'])}}

</div>

<div class="form-group">
Please Select A
<select class="js-states browser-default select2 form-control" name="coursename" required id="coursename">
    <option value="option_select" disabled selected>Course Name</option>
    @foreach($courses as $course)
        <option value="{{ $course->coursename }}" {{$course->coursename == $course->id  ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $course->coursename}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('taskduetime','Task Due Date')}}
    {{Form::date('taskduetime', \Carbon\Carbon::now(),['class'=>'form-control'])}}
</div>﻿
```

Comment: In my edit view{!! Form::open(['action' => ['TasksController@update',$task->id],'method' => 'POST']) !!}

Comment: First of all, I recommend you do not use this form package. You can do everything without this.

Comment: I found this form format in laravel collectives, what is another way to do dropdown and datetimepicker?

Comment: The error datetimepicker is "Cannot use object of type Carbon\Carbon as array". The error for dropdown is    Argument 4 passed to Collective\Html\FormBuilder::select() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many good javascript plugin available for datetime picker. To fine those search in google `datepicker`. I suggest you to use one of them & don't use laracollective's form.

Some of them are:

[Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Jquery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

[Datepicker](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/)